# SQL or returning less results

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm using mysql with a linked Access 2013 front.
So firstly I can get results using a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [name] LIKE '%test%';
```

However as soon as I throw in an or operator:

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [name] LIKE '%test%' OR [id] LIKE '%test%';
```

As far as I know each side of the OR operator should be evaluated to boolean values, left to right, then return a result as soon as one of them is true. But I'm getting less results than just querying the name on its own.

Any ideas? (Or questions)

Comment: with an OR  expression you could obtain more result taht just query  without or ..  (and not as soon is evalueated  becasue the query look for all the table rows)

Comment: sorry scaisEdge, I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Ideally I would like to look in all rows of the table, to see if either of the columns have results that match my query.

Comment: in the realty  .. the select scan all the rows .. and for each row begin eval the where condition for each OR condition and return soon an or condition is TRUE..  .. if you have two OR condition you should obatin in select more rows that with a single condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect answer, but you might be able to try:

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [name] LIKE '%test%' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE [id] LIKE '%test%';
```

Not very elegant, but it should get the job done.

Comment: the right asnwer  should be UNION  ..not UNION ALL  .. (UNION ALL Return two time the equal rows  ....UNION NOT)

Comment: Thank you both SandPiper and ScaisEdge. UNION has produced rows where results from both columns are returning.